# Can't compile and link a static library with clang

Tags: c, linux, clang

I'm trying to link a simple static library example but I can't get it work.

`addnumbers.c`

```
int addNumbers(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

`subnumbers.c`

```
int subNumbers(int x, int y)
{
    return x - y;
}
```

`clang -c subnumbers.c addnumbers.c`
`ar cr libmath.a addnumbers.o subnumbers.o`

So far so good I get my `libmath.a` static library.
Now let's get to the confusing part:

`math.h`

```
int addNumbers(int x, int y);
int subNumbers(int x, int y);
```

`demo.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "math.h"

int main()
{
    int nb1 = 23; 
    int nb2 = 45; 

    int result = addNumbers(nb1, nb2);
    printf("%d + %d = %d",nb1, nb2, result);
    return 0;
}
```

`clang -c demo.c`

I get a `demo.o` file but I can't execute it

`clang demo.c`

> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/demo-76a54f.o: in function `main': demo.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to` addNumbers'

Same thing with `clang demo.c -L libmath`
What am I missing ?

Comment: `clang demo.c -L . -lmath -o demo`? Also try avoiding well known names (*math.h*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-c` option tells the compiler to compile the code *without linking it*, so you get a `demo.o` object file with missing symbols.

To statically link your `libmath.a`, simply add it to the command line:

```bash
clang -c demo.c  # produces demo.o
clang -o demo demo.o libmath.a
./demo
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-L` switch is for specifying directories to look for libraries in.

The `-l` switch is for specifying libraries by abbreviating their names.

In `clang demo.c -L libmath`, `-L libmath` says “when looking for libraries, look in the directory named `libmath`.” That does not tell `clang` to look for a library, just where to look when it does look. By itself, that command will only look for the default libraries set when `clang` was built, such as the library that provides the standard C library routines and the C startup routine.

To tell `clang` to look for a library, you must either give `clang` the name of the library, such as `libmath.a`, or `-l` with an abbreviation for the library, such as `-lmath`: `clang demo.c libmath.a` or `clang demo.c -lmath`.

Comment: `clang demo.c libmath.a` works. `clang demo.c libmath.a -o demo` works as well if I want an executable file named differently. But `clang demo.c -lmath` generates an error: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmath: No such file or directory`. However `clang demo.c -L . -lmath -o demo`, as suggested above, works.